# Split a file between two specific values and put it in a array in perl

Tags: perl, file, text, split

Sample file:

```
### Current GPS Coordinates ###
Just In ... : unknown


### Power Source ###
 2

### TPM Status ###
 0

### Boot Version ###
GD35 1.1.0.12 - built 14:22:56, Jul 10 232323
```

I want split above file in to arrays like below:

`@Current0_PS_Coordinates` should be like below

```
### Current GPS Coordinates ###
Just In ... : unknown
```

I like to do it in Perl any help? (current program added from comment)

```
#!/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 -w
my @lines;
my $file;
my $lines;
my $i;
#chomp $i;
$file = 'test.txt'; # Name the file 
open(INFO, $file); # Open the file
@lines = <INFO>; # Read it into an array 
close(INFO); # Close the file
foreach my $line (@lines) { print "$line"; }
```

Comment: Have you written any code yet?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it. I have code till read the file in to an array. Looking for some help guys.

Comment: Add the code that you do have, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file line by line.  Use chomp to remove trailing newlines

If the input line matches this regexp `/^### (.*) ###/` then you have the name of an "array" in $1

It is possible to make named variables like @Current0_PS_Coordinates from these matches.

But it's better to use them as hash keys and then store the data in a hash that has arrays as it's values

So put the $1 from the match in "$lastmatch" and start an empty array referred to by a hash like this `$items{$lastmatch}=[]` for now and read some more

If the input line does not match the "name of an array" regexp given above and if it is not empty then we assume that it is a value for the last match found.  So it can be stuffed in the current array like this `push @$items{$lastmatch}, $line`

Once you've done this all the data will be available in the %items hash

See the perldata, perlre, perldsc and perllol documentation pages for more details

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be buying the book Learning Perl (O'Reilly). Seriously, it's a great book with interesting exercises at the end of each chapter. Very easy to learn.

1). Why do you have "my @lines" then "my $lines" lower down? I don't even think you're allowed to do that because scalars and arrays are the same variable but different context. For example, @list can be ('a', 'b', 'c') but calling $list would return 3, the number of items in that list.

2). What is "my $i"? Even if you're just writing down thoughts, try to use descriptive names. It'll make the code a lot easier to piece together.

3). Why is there a commented out "chomp $i"? Where were you going with that thought?

4). Try to use the 3 argument form of open. This will ensure you don't accidentally destroy files you're reading from:

```
open INFO, "<", $file;
```

If you're not sure where to start this problem, Vorsprung's answer probably won't mean anything. Regex and variables like $1 are things you'll need to read a book to understand.

Comment: Shawn, your point #1 is incorrect.  `@lines` and `$lines` are different variables.  They share the same identifier, but they are of different type.  To get the size of the array, you must simply use it in a `scalar` context:  `scalar(@lines)`